# How to create a delimited in SQL Server using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

[image: SSIS]

This is the table and I want only the last string after the ">" in SQL Server without blanks

Table SQL Server delimited:

```
Sports & Outdoors › Sports & Fitness › Leisure Sports & Game Room › Outdoor Games & Activities › Balls › Dodgeballs
Sports & Outdoors › Sports & Fitness › Leisure Sports & Game Room › Outdoor Games & Activities › Balls › Dodgeballs
Sports & Outdoors › Sports & Fitness › Accessories › Inflation Devices & Accessories
Sports & Outdoors › Sports & Fitness › Exercise & Fitness › Accessories › Jump Ropes
```

This is the result I need:

```
Dodgeballs
Dodgeballs
Inflation Devices & Accessories
Jump Ropes
```

This is the function in xls:

```
=trim(index(SPLIT(A1,"›"),1,COUNTA(SPLIT(A1,"›"))))
```

This is the SSIS :

```
TRIM(SUBSTRING([Categories: Tree],FINDSTRING([Categories: Tree],"›",1),LEN([Categories: Tree])))
```

Comment: for some reason when i copy the data from MSSQL it copy wrong; this is how it looks like https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MCiYI_CjHr7WZzw5ozxDtwZpOMfh7oMw/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use:

```
select t.*, 
       right(tree, charindex(' › ', reverse(tree)) - 1)
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d0f73d6df4f96d355a7fae262de95aa8) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

So you are using SSIS **Derived Column** Transformation.

A combination of two SSIS expression functions will produce what is needed: `TOKEN()` and `TOKENCOUNT()`. Plus the `TRIM()` function at the end

For SSIS variable:

```
TRIM(TOKEN(@[User::fileName], ">", TOKENCOUNT(@[User::fileName], ">")))
```

For a column in SSIS pipeline:

```
TRIM(TOKEN(ColumnName, ">", TOKENCOUNT(ColumnName, ">")))
```

Comment: this is the one I used in SSIS many thanks

Comment: @Chriswinter, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.